# Why do top conferences/journals between different research fields sometimes have a large difference in h5-index?

Tags: journals, conference, bibliometrics

Example: the top conferences/journals for computer vision have an h5-index almost twice higher than the top conferences/journals for natural language processing:

https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_computervisionpatternrecognition  ([mirror 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20210609054517/https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_computervisionpatternrecognition), [mirror 2](http://archive.today/EwKms)):

| Index | Publication | h5-index | h5-median |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | IEEE/CVF Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition | [299](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computervisionpatternrecognition&view_op=list_hcore&venue=w44irn7CFc0J.2020) | 509 |
| 2. | IEEE/CVF International Conference on Computer Vision | [176](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computervisionpatternrecognition&view_op=list_hcore&venue=uDnJSYNMB80J.2020) | 295 |
| 3. | European Conference on Computer Vision | [144](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computervisionpatternrecognition&view_op=list_hcore&venue=cwIh2C-xo8kJ.2020) | 286 |
| 4. | IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence | [131](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computervisionpatternrecognition&view_op=list_hcore&venue=FMIcylNwodUJ.2020) | 261 |
| 5. | IEEE Transactions on Image Processing | [113](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computervisionpatternrecognition&view_op=list_hcore&venue=nbL3lXiue2AJ.2020) | 156 |
| 6. | Pattern Recognition | [85](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computervisionpatternrecognition&view_op=list_hcore&venue=x0SOFhwf7eMJ.2020) | 126 |
| 7. | IEEE Computer Society Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition Workshops | [73](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computervisionpatternrecognition&view_op=list_hcore&venue=ihIDe6biV1gJ.2020) | 110 |
| 8. | International Journal of Computer Vision | [70](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computervisionpatternrecognition&view_op=list_hcore&venue=p7bWfTZ3kDQJ.2020) | 150 |
| 9. | Medical Image Analysis | [67](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computervisionpatternrecognition&view_op=list_hcore&venue=dlrWmqYJmF8J.2020) | 115 |
| 10. | Pattern Recognition Letters | [59](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computervisionpatternrecognition&view_op=list_hcore&venue=cr6slXz_0IoJ.2020) | 80 |

https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_computationallinguistics  ([mirror 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417075746/https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_computationallinguistics), [mirror 2](http://archive.today/Ui9ku)):

| # | Publication | h5-index | h5-median |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Meeting of the Association for Computational Linguistics (ACL) | [135](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computationallinguistics&view_op=list_hcore&venue=Y3UjV9bSCxMJ.2020) | 220 |
| 2. | Conference on Empirical Methods in Natural Language Processing (EMNLP) | [112](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computationallinguistics&view_op=list_hcore&venue=LqrQjvOguiMJ.2020) | 197 |
| 3. | Conference of the North American Chapter of the Association for Computational Linguistics: Human Language Technologies (HLT-NAACL) | [90](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computationallinguistics&view_op=list_hcore&venue=ORSK3meVbY4J.2020) | 148 |
| 4. | Transactions of the Association for Computational Linguistics | [53](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computationallinguistics&view_op=list_hcore&venue=NCymNpPEF_cJ.2020) | 112 |
| 5. | International Workshop on Semantic Evaluation | [50](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computationallinguistics&view_op=list_hcore&venue=nnrJuCTuhnwJ.2020) | 93 |
| 6. | International Conference on Computational Linguistics (COLING) | [49](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computationallinguistics&view_op=list_hcore&venue=6AfzgED5a7MJ.2020) | 73 |
| 7. | Conference of the European Chapter of the Association for Computational Linguistics (EACL) | [45](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computationallinguistics&view_op=list_hcore&venue=JnFTLT-D1FUJ.2020) | 68 |
| 8. | Conference on Computational Natural Language Learning (CoNLL) | [39](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computationallinguistics&view_op=list_hcore&venue=H7TUtVM_vm4J.2020) | 68 |
| 9. | International Conference on Language Resources and Evaluation (LREC) | [38](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computationallinguistics&view_op=list_hcore&venue=qf6JB6yXg1UJ.2020) | 54 |
| 10. | Workshop on Machine Translation | [35](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&vq=eng_computationallinguistics&view_op=list_hcore&venue=wNGM6_RkxKgJ.2020) | 64 |

Comment: Is it surprising that there would be different citation patterns between these two fields? C.f. [the case of journals](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1020/17254).

Comment: @Anyon great link, thanks!

Comment: For fun you should pull up a medical field such as cancer research.

Answer (score 9):

Different fields have different sizes, speed and publication culture. Thus, it is completely expected that h5-indices will vary a lot between fields. This effect is going to be more pronounced when larger values are considered.

Size: To push an h5-index from eg 199 to 200, the additional paper needs to be cited 200 times within 5 years. In a smaller field, this could easily mean getting citations from an absurdly high fraction of the new papers published.

Speed: The h5-index only counts citations in a 5-year window. In a fast moving field, that doesn't matter much. In a slower-moving field, this can easily ignore most of the potential citations a paper could get.

Publication culture: How big or small are the units people publish? How many references does a typical paper have? Do authors always explicitly cite the masters, or only if really needed?